# Green Hexagons Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, visual, optimization, cellular-automata

Start by choosing some hexagons to be green. If a hexagon is touching at least 3 green hexagons, it becomes green. This repeats for as long as possible. What's the minimal number of initial green hexagons to make all hexagons green? Here we see 3 layers of hexagons. What if there were n layers?

[image]

Comment: Is this an [optimization] problem? If so, are you aware of a provably optimal solution?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Look at the center hexagon in the grid pictured. That's a grid with 1 layer. Now surround that with 6 hexagons. That's a grid with 2 layers. The grid pictured has 3 layers, etc.

Comment: @bobble I had a solution which I suspected was minimal, but no proof. The answer by Quuxplusone beats my solution, so I guess I have an upper bound. If this question no longer belongs here we can delete it, but I think it would be interesting to hear what others have to say regarding an upper bound or proof of an optimal solution, so personally, I hope it's acceptable as is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For three layers of hexagons, the minimal answer is

> **five**

:

> ```
>           .
>         .   .
>       G   G   G
>         .   .
>       .   .   .
>         G   .
>       .   .   .
>         .   .
>           G
> ```

which fills in like this. `1` hexes fill in on turn 1, `2` on turn 2, etc., until the whole board is green after turn 6.

> ```
>           5
>         2   4
>       G   G   G
>         1   3
>       2   2   5
>         G   4
>       5   3   .
>         4   5
>           G
> ```

I have no particular insight into the general solution for larger boards.

UPDATE: For four layers (37 cells), the minimal solution is

> **seven**:
>
> ```
>            9
>          5   8
>        2   4   7
>      G   G   G   G
>        1   3   6
>      2   2   5   8
>        G   4   7
>      5   3   6   9
>        4   5   8
>      9   G   7   .
>        8   6   9
>          7   8
>            G
> ```

This pattern already strongly suggests that the answer for n layers is always

> 2n+1

initially green tiles, laid out in the

> "7"-shaped

pattern apparent from these examples.

Comment: I thought the answer was 6, so this is very interesting. Based on your answer, I think every time you add a layer, you add 2 greens, maintaining the < shape for the initial configuration, but I don't have a proof this is minimal.

Comment: I think you mean to say "four layers"

Comment: (...and so your answer for n layers is correctly incorrect.)

Comment: @RichardBirkett: Thanks — edited!

Answer (score 13):

Proof that 5 is minimal:

> Note that the perimeter of the green region never increases.  Every time a hexagon turns green, you lose at least 3 edges, and gain at most 3 edges.  Since the final configuration has a perimeter of 30, there must be at least 30/6 = 5 green hexagons at the start.

For larger configurations, this gives a lower bound of

> 2n-1 hexagons

Comment: Remark: @Quuxplusone gave a strategy that attains this bound, so we have optimised the problem. If the proof of their strategy for n layers is not obvious, I am happy to provide it in an answer, but the credit should be theirs. It is a proof by induction.

Comment: @RichardBirkett Please do!

Comment: FWIW, I gave an *apparent* strategy that attains this bound. I didn't prove that my strategy always does fill the whole board (for larger n). It sure looks like it does; and I bet someone can prove it in a single paragraph that's obvious in hindsight; but *I* don't take any credit for proving it. :) Btw, the very neat trick of trading off perimeter for area is used to even greater effect in [Green Triangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120854/3896)!